# How to specify a weak relationship (dashed line) in an entity relationship diagram using crow's foot notation on Visio?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, visio, erd

I am having issues trying to specify a weak relationship (dashed line) on Microsoft Visio when designing an entity relationship diagram using crow's foot notation. Though I am able to add arrows representing strong relationships (solid line) between two entities, when I try to change the line style to any type of dashed line, it automatically reverts to a solid line. Nevertheless, I am able to change the line weight, color, and so on. How can I change this?

[I found an archived answer to this question from 2011 on Microsoft Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f52d3ab8-0f46-4626-b8ad-ce74043ade51/crow8217s-foot-cardinality-problem-er-diagram?forum=visiogeneral) but the answers seem to be outdated and the diagram outlining the steps seems to be deleted ([and not archived on the web](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/806/visio2010relationshipwo.jpg/)). I searched but haven't found any past questions related to this on Stack Overflow.

An image showing the issue is shown below:
[image]

Note that this occurs on both Visio Online and on the Visio application. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the line, right-click and turn off **Set Identifying**.

Comment: I've tried this before, but that option doesn't show up on my end. (See: https://i.imgur.com/GO5pjab.png) Any ideas why?

Comment: 4th item down if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If you'll believe it, my eyes glanced over that option for months...